# CALL_EXCEPTION when calling a simple view function with ethers.js, but not in my hardhat test

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat

UPDATE:
The short description is this function works the contract is deployed on Mumbai Polygon, but fails in Hardhat locally.

Details:

Here is my simple function which has no issue when testing, but breaks when trying to execute from the front end

```
function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

My front end code is such:

```
const localNodeProvider = ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545')
const c = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", MyContract.abi, localNodeProvider)
const balance = await c.getContractBalance()
console.log(balance.toNumber())
```

I get this exception thrown below.

```
{"reason":null,"code":"CALL_EXCEPTION","method":"getContractBalance()","data":"0x","errorArgs":null,"errorName":null,"errorSignature":null,"address":"0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3","args":[],"transaction":{"data":"0x6f9fb98a","to":"0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3","from":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266"}}
```

When I use a Web3Provider, getContractBalance also fails.  However, other functions that are not view but are payable seem to work fine.

```
const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
                const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
                const signer = provider.getSigner()
                const contract = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", PictosPointsBank.abi, signer)
                await contract.getContractBalance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii even I ran out in the same issue...The problem with me was My metamask was connected to another `network`. I switched to `hardhat network` in metamask it worked.